# Как растягивать GridView по размеру окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется окно. На нём ListView. В нём GridView. При горизонтальном растяжении окна происходит следующее: все колонки остаются своей ширины (т.к. Width задан явно, чтобы колонки не растягивались за границы экрана при большом объёме содержимого), за последней колонкой появляется ещё одна пустая и растягивается именно она. Код соответствующих элементов представлен ниже (многоточиями заменены названия, не имеющие принципиального значения):

```xml
             <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding ...}">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" MaxHeight="36" MaxWidth="36" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="...">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="..." Width="250">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding ...}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="..." Width="250">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding ...}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы GridView корректно подгонялся под ширину окна: не выходил за его границы при объёмном содержимом, но изменял свои размеры вслед за окном.

Comment: Ну так наверно надо отказаться от статичного размера колонки, установите `*` с нужной вам цифрой, разделите все на нужные вам "куски", если хотите ограничить размер, то ставьте `MaxWidth`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ звёздочка не ставится, выдаёт ошибку. Если установить макс. размер, то при дальнейшем растяжении окна появляется пустое поле.

Comment: Попробуйте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309249/listview-gridviewcolumn-width)

Comment: @aepot это навело на верные мысли об использовании `Binding` + `Converter`, спасибо.